# why PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer ignores value from property file

Tags: java, spring-boot, properties-file

In SpringBoot, in order to setup database connection I've put DB properties inside the property file

**mysql.properties**

```
driverClassName = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/musicdb?useSSL=true
username = prospring5
password = prospring5
```

also provided configuration file

**MysqlConfig.java**

```
package pl.boot.music;

import java.sql.Driver;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Lazy;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.SimpleDriverDataSource;

@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:mysql.properties")
public class MysqlConfig {

    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MysqlConfig.class);

    @Value("${driverClassName}")
    private String driverClassName;
    @Value("${url}")
    private String url;
    @Value("${username}")
    private String username;
    @Value("${password}")
    private String password;

    @Lazy
    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        try {
            SimpleDriverDataSource dataSource = new SimpleDriverDataSource();
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            Class<? extends Driver> driver = (Class<? extends Driver>) Class.forName(driverClassName);
            dataSource.setDriverClass(driver);

            logger.debug("url = {" + url + "}");
            dataSource.setUrl(url);
            logger.debug("username = {" + username + "}");
            dataSource.setUsername(username);
            logger.debug("password = {" + password + "}");
            dataSource.setPassword(password);

            return dataSource;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

*(no need for static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer bean, SpringBoot includes the file automatically)*

Now, when I try to test as following:

**MusicBootApplicationTests.java**

```
package pl.boot.music;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

@SpringBootTest
public class MusicBootApplicationTests {

    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MusicBootApplicationTests.class);

    @Test
    public void testDataSource() throws SQLException {
        GenericApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(MysqlConfig.class);
        DataSource dataSource = ctx.getBean("dataSource", DataSource.class);
        Connection connection = null;
        try {
            connection = dataSource.getConnection();
            PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT 1");
            ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery();
            while (resultSet.next()) {
                int mockVal = resultSet.getInt("1");
                assertTrue(mockVal == 1);
            }
            statement.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            logger.debug("Something unexpected happened.", e);
            throw e;
        } finally {
            if (connection != null) {
                try {
                    connection.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }
            ctx.close();
        }
    }
}
```

the value assigned to @Value("${username}") is from the operating system - not the property file...

```
11:02:43.202 [main] DEBUG p.s.b.m.MysqlConfig - url = {jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/musicdb?useSSL=true}
11:02:43.212 [main] DEBUG p.s.b.m.MysqlConfig - username = {Przemysław Lastname}
11:02:43.212 [main] DEBUG p.s.b.m.MysqlConfig - password = {prospring5}
11:02:43.454 [main] DEBUG p.s.b.m.MusicBootApplicationTests - Something unexpected happened.
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'PrzemysÅ‚aw Lastname'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:965)
```

Of course, I can choose another name for my "username" property which solves this problem but questions are a little broader:

1) why the value from property file does not override the value from the environment?

2) how do force spring-boot to override the value from the environment by the property from the property file?

3) where can I find the list of "environment properties" which can't be replaced by the values from property files?

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>pl.boot.music</groupId>
    <artifactId>preliminary</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>MusicBoot</name>
    <description>Music DB Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: The order in which configuration sources are considered is specified here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html

Answer (score 0):

Please review: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html

> 1) why the value from property file does not override the value from the environment?

**By design**, environment variables are considered before values from a bundled `@PropertySource`

> 2) how do force spring-boot to override the value from the environment by the property from the property file?

By removing it from the environment, but more likely you would specify the values on the command line. If this is a unit test, use `@TestPropertySource`, which overrides almost everything else.

> 3) where can I find the list of "environment properties" which can't be replaced by the values from property files?

See above link. It is not about which properties, but simply where the properties are defined.